# Does SwiftyJson make parsing swift json faster?

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I've recently made a weather that gets data from open weather map, but it takes *forever* for the parsed data to show up on the screen...
With code like this:

```
let tempF = jsonResult["tempFahrenheit"]
```

I know the data is fast because I watch the url result show up immediately in the console, so would swiftyjson speed up displaying data on the screen? Is there a swiftyjson for Swift 3??

Comment: It would be good if you can show me your parsing code and ui update. The problem is not relate with sifty json. Its something else.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted doesn't appear to update any UI element on the screen.

If there is another place where you are updating the UI with something like

`mylabel.text = someVariable`

and the UI is still laggy, it maybe because you have not wrapped the UI 
change in the main thread.

The correct way to do the update above would be

`DispatchQueue.main.async { mylabel.text = someVariable }`

Comment: So I would just put that inside of the view controller viewDidLoad? I still don't understand what would be taking so long for it to update the screen once I get the data...

Comment: You have to update the UI on the main thread why is explained here, https://www.quora.com/Why-must-the-UI-always-be-updated-on-Main-Thread

Comment: Can the     DispatchQueue.main.async 
be inside of a function? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Call API> Get Response> Parse Data > Update UI [It should be in main queue]

Write your UI update related code in main queue like below ...

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 textFiled.text = yourText
 imageview.image = yourImage
.......
}
```